# Should I gift my squadmates Chocolates or Tennyson?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was in the Heurta Memorial Hospital on the Citadel when I discovered a Sirta Corp shop that sold miscellaneous items: Chocolates, Books, and collections of Poetry.

Judging by the nature of these, I'm assuming that they're intended to be given to Shepard's hospital-stricken squadmate in a "get-well-soon" gesture. I know from ME 1 that Ash has a soft spot for Tennyson, but I'm unsure about the effectiveness of other gifts, or what works well for Kaiden.

Who has a soft spot for elcor poetry? Yes. *Elcor*.

Which squadmate prefers which gifts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gift only matters for the injured squadmate you'll need to visit in the hospital. As you've noted, Ashley prefers Tennyson.

Kaidan, being a far more practical sort, prefers whiskey.