# Should I buy my girl flowers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I gift my squadmates Chocolates or Tennyson?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53568/should-i-gift-my-squadmates-chocolates-or-tennyson)

There are quite a few stores in *Mass Effect 3*, but not all of them seem useful. For example:

I noticed that the store in Huerta Medical on the Citadel sells things like Flowers, and Candy Assortments, along with various book collections. Now, while i do have a jilted ex-lover in the hospital, I'm not sure if buying her the flowers will actually *do* anything beneficial to my game.

**What do these items do? Do they serve a purpose or are they just flair?**

Comment: Crap, it is. I missed that one in the barrage of ME3 questions.