# How do I give Ashley the roses I purchased?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3, how can I give Ashley the roses I bought in the hospital after she wakes up?

Comment: I didn't even know you could do this!

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53568/15643

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buying the right item will show you giving the gift to your injured squadmate when you visit. For Ashely it seems you want to get the Tennyson, and if you have Kaiden, get the Whiskey. [This thread](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/355/index/9678754/1) indicates that you will give them during the conversation if you purchase them.

Comment: tennyson is the flowers right?

Comment: no, Tennyson is the poetry books

Comment: Tennyson is a reference to the poem "Ulysses". Should be one of the books.

Comment: may be because i bought the wrong gift so that erased although i bough it far in the first time i entred the hospital you know thank you all for help and last question is there will be another chance to buy the right gift or that was one shot time?

Comment: @crouch That I'm not sure honestly. You can either ask a new question about it (though might want to generalize) or, my recommendation, just try it. Though I've read somewhere that says the gifts disappear after the first meeting so I don't know.

Comment: i don't want to ask again that may become spam and i already played so far after so to the hell with the gift i think that's my second question if i didn't give her a gift is that gonna break some thing in our relationship? thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

No you won't break your relationship if you get her the 'wrong' gift, or no gift at all.  You will have time (through conversations with her later), to continue your romance.  (Just be nice to her the rest of the way.)

As for the 'correct' gift to purchase for her?  It is the Tennyson poetry books.  Remember in ME1 all of the poetry she quoted?  Buying her those books shows her that you 'remembered'.  All of the other gifts listed are just a waste of credits and will never be used, or shown being given to her.  And you will give her the gift on your 2nd meeting with her in the hospital.  (Once she awakens from her concussion)