# How do I give gifts?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I give Ashley the roses I purchased?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55509/how-do-i-give-ashley-the-roses-i-purchased)

I remember in DA: Origins, you talked to them or something, but I don't know how it works in this game. I bought them all from the medical store in the hospital, but I don't know how to give them to my love interests. Help?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only give gifts during romance scenes or when Ashley gets out of the hospital.

Comment: Should be "Ashley or Kaiden", depending on who you offed in ME1.  (I offed Ashley, personally.)